# Android: Trying to have buttons in TableLayout to be all the same size and stretch out to fill the screen width

Tags: android

I'm making a sound board.  I have a tablelayout of 2 by 8.  I would like it so the buttons are all the same size and will stretch out to fill the screen width.  I tried setting the width t fill_parent, but then  their was only one button per row instad of 2.  Right now I have the size set to a fix number.

xml file

android:orientation="horizontal" >

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/butVol"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Vol" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/butRingtone"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"

         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Make Into Ringtone" />
```

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="#ff888888"
android:orientation="vertical" >
```

```
      <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="1dip" >

  <Button
        android:id="@+id/but1"
         android:layout_width="150dp"
         android:text="begin" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/but2"
         android:layout_width="150dp"
         android:text="evening" /> 


</TableRow>

 <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="1dip" >

<Button
        android:id="@+id/but3"
         android:layout_width="150dp"
         android:text="freak" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/but4"
         android:layout_width="150dp"
         android:text="go" /> 


</TableRow>

 <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="1dip" >


</TableRow>

      <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="1dip" >


     <Button
        android:id="@+id/but5"
         android:layout_width="150dp"
         android:text="hello" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/but6"
         android:layout_width="150dp"
         android:text="hitme" /> 

</TableRow> 
 <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="1dip" >

   <Button
        android:id="@+id/but7"
         android:layout_width="150dp"
         android:text="I like that" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/but8"
         android:layout_width="150dp"
         android:text="laugh" /> 

</TableRow>

     <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="1dip" >

   <Button
        android:id="@+id/but9"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:text="My Card" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/but10"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:text="Nerves" /> 

</TableRow>
  <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="1dip" >

   <Button
        android:id="@+id/but11"
         android:layout_width="150dp"
         android:text="Plan" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/but12"
         android:layout_width="150dp"
         android:text="Poor choice" /> 

</TableRow>   

 <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="1dip" >

   <Button
        android:id="@+id/but13"
         android:layout_width="150dp"
         android:text="Rule" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/but14"
         android:layout_width="150dp"
         android:text="Serious" /> 

</TableRow>     

     <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="1dip" >

   <Button
        android:id="@+id/but15"
         android:layout_width="150dp"
         android:text="smile" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/but16"
         android:layout_width="150dp"
         android:text="word" /> 

</TableRow>
```

Comment: Try with "layout_weight" attribute.

Comment: You have posted enough questions here (~300) to know how to properly indent your code. Why should we take time to answer your question if you won't put in the effort yourself?

Comment: Hi,Yes you are right,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make your table row as below...

```
<TableRow
      android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:padding="1dip" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/but1"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:text="begin" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/but2"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:text="evening" />
```

Comment: please try and properly put your question content from next time...n tnx